# How to setup AWS KMS on Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Can you please advice if Airflow supports AWS KMS server side encryption? If yes, is there any documentation on how to setup? I am using Airflow 1.9.0 version.

I tried with creating s3 connection with extra args like -

{"aws_access_key_id":"xx", "aws_secret_access_key": "xx", "sse": "aws:kms", "sse-kms-key-id": "xx"}

and used s3 hook to upload a file in the code but it is throwing this error -

an error occurred (accessdenied) when calling the createmultipartupload operation access denied

Where as s3 cp from command line did work!

aws s3 cp test.txt s3://xxx/xx/test.txt --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id "xx"
upload: ./test.txt to s3://xxx/xx/test.txt

thanks in advance.